# jQuery Highstocks not rendering - dates are 1970

Tags: jquery, highcharts

```
<script>
    $(document).ready( function() {
    var seriesOptions = [];

/**
 * Create the chart when all data is loaded
 * @returns {undefined}
 */
function createChart() {

    Highcharts.stockChart('chart23', {

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },
        exporting: {
             enabled: false
    },
        yAxis: {

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },
        plotOptions:{
            series:{
                turboThreshold:0
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2,
            split: true
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}


    seriesOptions[0] = {
        name: 'CREATED',
        data: [1491292800000,18,1491296400000,31,1491300000000,30,1491303600000,46,1491307200000,37] // ADDED BRACKETS
    };
    seriesOptions[1] = {
        name: 'RESOLVED',
        data: [1491292800000,18,1491296400000,31,1491300000000,30,1491303600000,46,1491307200000,37] // ADDED BRACKETS
    };
        createChart();
    });
    </script>
```

The chart x/y axis are being rendered but no lines/data and the dates are set to 1970

EDIT: I put the brackets in as stated and data showed but it was up/down in zig zag pattern

[image]

Any ideas? Sorry - this is all I have at the moment. The data is being passed via a PHP variable so no need for JSON

Comment: What date format does the library expect? I can't believe both 1491292800000 and 18 comply with it :-?

Comment: The example on the site uses https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=msft-c.json&callback=jQuery311029039657663166296_1495278355765&_=1495278355766 for the data which I'm mirroring. Their example is here http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

Comment: The example contains two data sets, one for big numbers that seems to be dates (I guess they're Unix timestamps multiplied by 1000) and another for small ones that seem to be actual plotted values. Yours have two (identical?) data sets that mix both kind of numbers, thus the zig-zag.

Comment: I copied/pasted wrong data but this has now been resolved thank you. The data was not in JSON format

Comment: Alright, thanks for reporting back. I'm casting a close vote, but I can retract it if you think you can share an answer that's useful for other people facing the same issue.

Comment: I wouldn't say it would be useful - just had to ensure the data was valid JSON